# When to use $.extend({...})?

Tags: jquery

my question is when do i should use $.extend(...) ?
In many jquery plugins i see that the jquery-object itself is extended with new (global) functions:

```
$.extend({
    doSth: function() {
        alert('do sth here');
    }
}
```

What are the advantages of extending the jquery-object instead of creating a global object containing the function:

```
var myLib = {
    doSth: function() {
        alert('do sth here');
    }
}
```

Currently i am developing a small js-lib. In that lib the $.fn-object is extended and i need some global functions.
But i don't know where to put the global functions: in my own lib-object or in the jquery-object?

Best Regards,
Biggie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*To give some context since it's not entirely clear from the question:* For those unaware, [`$.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) with a single parameter extends the `jQuery` object.

---

Often there is no *need* for this, unless you're adding something *very* library related, I'd keep it in your own namespace.  It serves no purpose under `$` and the only possible thing that can happen is a potential naming conflict later with new jQuery core updates.

If you have one or two static methods that go with a plugin, where you're extending both `$.fn` *and* `$` then I'd see it as acceptable, but if you have many methods (which sounds like the case) there's no real benefit to them being on `$`.

Honestly the reason the single argument versions exists (or, more accurately, was added in the first place) is *for jQuery itself*, for internal usage (pretty much every "section" uses it, check it out [here](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L122), [here](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes.js#L241) and [here](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/data.js#L6) as examples), I'm not sure that external uses were ever *intended*, they just left it open/extensible for that.

Comment: "the reason the single argument versions exists is for jQuery itself" -- and for plugins as well.

Comment: @lonesomeday - Not really, the reason it was *added* was for jQuery, though plugins *can* use it, most plugins will extend `jQuery.fn`, *not* jQuery, plugins don't *need* their static functions on the jQuery object, they do however *have* to be on `$.fn` to be used in chains.

Comment: Sorry, was getting ahead of myself.

Comment: @lonesomeday - It's a valid point, I updated to hopefully address it more clearly, I see how you could read it that way....hopefully clearer now :)